# ListView Showing 1 result using FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-cardview

"In My Application ,I am allowing to add comments using "`ListView`" ,and using "`FirebaseListAdapter`", it works ,but it shows 1 item only, and i don't know if the problem in "`Java code`" or "`xml code`", i previewed related `codes` below,
tip: this `code` is inside `fragment`,and i have used "`FireBaseRecyclerAdapter`" in other things and worked, but currently i face problem with `Listview` while i need to use it."

```
{   DatabaseReference commentsdb = mydatabase.getReference().child("comments");
  Query commentsquery = commentsdb.child(storyNAME).orderByChild("currentstoryname").equalTo(storyNAME).limitToFirst(10);

FirebaseListOptions<comments> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<comments>()
            .setQuery(commentsquery, comments.class)
            .setLayout(R.layout.comments)
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .build();
                                         fbla= new FirebaseListAdapter<comments>(options) {
                                        @Override
                                        protected void populateView(View v, comments model, int position) {

                                            ((TextView)v.findViewById(id.commentername)).setText(model.getUserName1());

                                            ((TextView)v.findViewById(id.commentstxt1)).setText(model.getUsercomment());
            comlist.setAdapter(fbla);
    fbla.startListening();

}

    {
```

This is my .XML file:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/commentsview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        ><ImageButton
        android:background="@drawable/ic_clear_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/cmtexitbtn"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />
<ListView
          android:id="@+id/commentslist"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:listitem="@layout/comments"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
       <!--</LinearLayout>-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"><ImageButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:id="@+id/comerimg"
                android:background="@drawable/imgstyle"
                android:clickable="false"
                /><EditText
                android:hint="type your comment"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/usernewcomment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/normaledittextsty" />
                <Button
                    android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="true"
                android:id="@+id/sendcombtn"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_send_24dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            }
```

Comment: You also should share the code whre you are getting the reference. In the meanwhile, if you are interested, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is how you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: I have added refs , Recyclerview works well with me , but FirebaseListAdapter is showing 1 item of 20 item ,so i don't know where the problem with it

Comment: See also the .XML file.

Comment: it is added after java code ,,,,,,tip this xml code is in card view

Comment: That's not correct. You are using the parten view using `android:visibility="invisible"`. Try to add only the views that you need as in my post.

Comment: haven't worked it is still showing  1 item,     sry it worked thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the latest comments and the edited post, the problem in the code was happening due the use of the following line of code:

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

The partent view was always set as `invisible`. The problem was solved by setting the visibility as `visible` and by adding to the partent view only the necessary views.